# Haproxy running error?

Tags: ubuntu, haproxy

I'm using HA-Proxy version 1.3.22 and Ubuntu 10.04. Here is my Configuration file.

```
global
        maxconn     25000  
        daemon
        nbproc      4 



defaults
        mode        http
        clitimeout  60000
        srvtimeout  30000
        contimeout  4000
        timeout http-request 5s  
        option      httpclose 




listen  http_proxy *:80
        #bind *:80
        balance roundrobin 
        option httpchk
        option forwardfor 
        use_backend bk_web_static if { path_end .jpg .png .gif .css .js }
        default_backend bk_web 


backend bk_web  

        balance roundrobin ## change to URL hashing

        server server1 0.0.0.0:3002 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
        server server2 0.0.0.0:3003 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
        server server3 0.0.0.0:3004 weight 1 maxconn 512 check



backend bk_web_static
  balance roundrobin
        server server1 0.0.0.0:3002 weight 1 maxconn 1000 check
        server server2 0.0.0.0:3006 weight 1 maxconn 1000 check
        server server3 0.0.0.0:3007 weight 1 maxconn 1000 check
```

I'm getting following error while running haproxy. I found this configuration code on net. i guess that code was for some latest version. please tell me what changes shuold i make to run haproxy server..

```
 [ALERT] 290/100612 (2745) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:24] : error detected while parsing switching rule.
[ALERT] 290/100612 (2745) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 290/100612 (2745) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

Comment: Indicate line number 24 please ???

Answer (score 0):

Try with this conf on your listen session:

```
listen  http_proxy *:80
        balance roundrobin 
        option httpchk
        option forwardfor 

        acl is_static path_end -i .jpg .png .gif .css .js 
        use_backend bk_web_static if is_static

        default_backend bk_web
```